# Parquet data and partition issue in Spark Structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, parquet, spark-structured-streaming

I am using Spark Structured streaming; My DataFrame has the following schema

```
root 
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true) 
 |    |-- zoneId: string (nullable = true) 
 |    |-- deviceId: string (nullable = true) 
 |    |-- timeSinceLast: long (nullable = true) 
 |-- date: date (nullable = true)
```

How can I do a writeStream with Parquet format and write the data 
(containing zoneId, deviceId, timeSinceLast; everything except date) and partition the data by date ? I tried the following code and the partition by clause did 
not work

```scala
val query1 = df1 
  .writeStream 
  .format("parquet") 
  .option("path", "/Users/abc/hb_parquet/data") 
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/Users/abc/hb_parquet/checkpoint") 
  .partitionBy("data.zoneId") 
  .start()
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to partition by date then you have to use it in `partitionBy()` method.

```scala
val query1 = df1 
  .writeStream 
  .format("parquet") 
  .option("path", "/Users/abc/hb_parquet/data") 
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/Users/abc/hb_parquet/checkpoint") 
  .partitionBy("date") 
  .start()
```

In case if you want to partition data structured by `<year>/<month>/<day>` you should make sure that the `date` column is of `DateType` type and then create columns appropriately formatted:

```scala
val df = dataset.withColumn("date", dataset.col("date").cast(DataTypes.DateType))

df.withColumn("year", functions.date_format(df.col("date"), "YYYY"))
  .withColumn("month", functions.date_format(df.col("date"), "MM"))
  .withColumn("day", functions.date_format(df.col("date"), "dd"))
  .writeStream 
  .format("parquet") 
  .option("path", "/Users/abc/hb_parquet/data") 
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/Users/abc/hb_parquet/checkpoint") 
  .partitionBy("year", "month", "day")
  .start()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try the method `repartition` which can take two kinds of arguments:

- column name
- number of wanted partitions.

I suggest using `repartition("date")` to partition your data by date.

A great link on the subject: https://hackernoon.com/managing-spark-partitions-with-coalesce-and-repartition-4050c57ad5c4